# How go to specific detail View?

Tags: sapui5

I start from this example https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#demoapps.html
The standard routing is of for me but I want a particular behavior...
I want that at start in detail I show a specific view: I have modified the routing:

```
routing : {
            config : {
                viewType : "XML",
                viewPath : "sap.ui.demo.poa.view",
                targetControl : "splitApp",
                clearTarget : false
            },
            routes : [
                {
                    pattern : "",
                    name : "master",
                    view : "Master",
                    viewLevel : 0,
                    targetAggregation : "masterPages",
                    subroutes : [
                        {
                            pattern : "detail/{detailId}",
                            name : "detail",
                            view : "Detail",
                            viewLevel : 1,
                            targetAggregation : "detailPages",
                            subroutes : [
                                {
                                    pattern : "detail/{detailId}/lineItemId/:lineItemId:",
                                    name : "lineItem",
                                    view : "LineItem",
                                    viewLevel : 2,
                                    targetAggregation : "detailPages"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            pattern : "{all*}",
                            name : "notFound",
                            view : "NotFound",
                            targetAggregation : "detailPages"
                        },
                        {
                            pattern : "{all*}",
                            name : "DetailActivity",
                            view : "DetailActivity",
                            targetAggregation : "detailPages"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

How can I show `DetailActivity` view at startup??

Answer (score 0):

To show `DetailActivity` at startup simply set it's route `pattern` to `""`.

Also, be aware that

```
pattern : "",
```

and

```
pattern : "{all*}",
```

should appear at most 1x each.

`pattern : ""` indicates the startup view and `pattern : "{all*}"` is a catch-all: meaning that any `route` not serviced by the other routes will point to it.

NB. each `route` should be unique and not hide other routes.

In your case the following may be closer to what you are looking for:

```
routing : {
    config : {
        viewType : "XML",
        viewPath : "sap.ui.demo.poa.view",
        targetControl : "splitApp",
        clearTarget : false
    },
    routes : [
        {
            pattern : "master",
            name : "master",
            view : "Master",
            viewLevel : 0,
            targetAggregation : "masterPages",
            subroutes : [
                {
                    pattern : "detail/{detailId}",
                    name : "detail",
                    view : "Detail",
                    viewLevel : 1,
                    targetAggregation : "detailPages",
                    subroutes : [
                        {
                            pattern : "detail/{detailId}/lineItemId/:lineItemId:",
                            name : "lineItem",
                            view : "LineItem",
                            viewLevel : 2,
                            targetAggregation : "detailPages"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    pattern : "",
                    name : "DetailActivity",
                    view : "DetailActivity",
                    targetAggregation : "detailPages"
                },
                {
                    pattern : "{all*}",
                    name : "notFound",
                    view : "NotFound",
                    targetAggregation : "detailPages"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the catchall route apply before DetailActivity in your example?